# Why exporting to SVG reduce quality rendering?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, svg, image-quality, rotate

I'm using `Adobe Illustrator CS6`.

Once I export a (rotated) `Area Type Text` in `SVG` and I view at 100%, I can see it with low quality rendering:

[image]

Only once I start to increase the zoom I gain quality:

[image]

I'm on Windows, and I'm using `Impact` as Font. Where's the trouble?

Comment: Have you tried converting the text to outlines?  I can't replicate the problem using Chrome or Firefox to view an SVG, with Impact text converted to outlines.  What browser are you using to view the SVG?

Comment: See example [SVG here](http://svgur.com/i/7CJ.svg)

Comment: I can see without any problem your text/example. Not sure why I can't do it myself. What do you mean "converting the text to outlines"? I simply add an Area Type Text with illustrator.

Comment: Select the text Object, and click Object > Expand. This converts the text to outlines, then export your SVG.

Comment: I see, now it works! Nice. So for every text I need to convert it every time? (if you place the answer, you got +1 and accepted)

Comment: Yes. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem the text is rendered badly because you have not converted it to outlines.

Select the text object, and click *Object > Expand*.  Then export your SVG.

This converts the text to outlines.

If you don't convert to outlines, then you are reliant on the viewer having the font installed (which might not always be the case), and also on the browser for rendering it. I suspect that's the problem you are having.

Comment: Your still at mercy of the rendering of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand something about rendering.

It is a sort of reinterpretation. The same as a musical piece, which had the instructions to be played in a partiture, but it is reinterpreted by the artist.

In this case, every browser takes the instructions given on an SVG file and reinterpret it. They render it, they do not just present it.

So different browsers have different render engines and reinterpret different stuff in different manners.

Some can alias or antialias things, some can just make a quick render, some can smooth things in a subpixel level.

You can not control that. That is given by the render engine and the settings of the user, if the case.

What is happening in the small version is that. Your render engine is making an aliased rendering.

Instead of watching a line of 1.5 pixels width (which you can not have) you are seeing let's say a 2px line.

Some other render engine or method could make a 1 px line and another line of another tone of gray to simulate the 1/2 pixel.

---

What you can try is to either to leave the text as text or to convert it to curves. Hoping that most render engines interpret one method better than the other.